# Update JavaScript object property value, push to array, and then set back to original value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, javascript-objects

I am trying to update a Javascript object value so that I can push it into an new array for filtering, but I then need to reset the object's property value back to its original value for when the user removes the filter (the user can toggle it on and off). I have tried everything I have seen here on stackoverflow and nothing has seemed to work. I have tried:

```
if (ctrl.dataArray.indexOf(row) === -1) {
    var rowCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(row));
    row.$$treeLevel = 0;
    ctrl.dataArray.push(row);
    row.$$treeLevel = rowCopy.$$treeLevel;
}
```

I've also tried:

```
if (ctrl.dataArray.indexOf(row) === -1) {
    var rowCopy = angular.copy(row);
    row.$$treeLevel = 0;
    ctrl.dataArray.push(row);
    row.$$treeLevel = rowCopy.$$treeLevel;
}
```

I'm essentially trying to update grid rows to show grids matching specific criteria, then set the grid back to it original state after the filter. I know the dataArray is getting updated with the "originalCopy" value after I am pushing into the array.But how can I keep this from happening?

I have to push the original row so the user can update it and then reset the filter and keep the updated grid cell value for saving.

How can I make my above code work?

Comment: What is the issue with code at Question?

Comment: Not sure the cause of your bug - but you might be making this more complex than it needs to be.  You could implement filtering for the grid by putting a `visible` boolean on each row object, setting it to false if the row doesn't pass the filter, then loop through your rows and draw only the ones where `visible === true`

Comment: `classList.toggle('myEffectOrLook')`

Comment: This data is coming from the database, adding a property would be the easiest solution but I'm not sure if that is possible. I can look into that.

Comment: @RonRoyston can you describe your solution in more detail

Comment: Actually changing the hidden property to true or false is the same thing as I have essentially. you would have to push all rows with visbile = true into an array. That has the same effect as me just commenting out this line: row.$$treeLevel = 0; I need it to be zero or the filtered rows are nested incorrectly